# MPMoviePlayer setCurrentPlayBackTime not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

MPMoviePlayerController   i am playing a video and when i pause a video, when i click button i want forward the video by some time. Does any one know how to forward video from current time ? if yes what is the minimum time that i can forward video ? like is it millisecond
 or seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeking very much depends on your content. Factors influencing the skip-able durations are: content format (MP4 local/progressive download or HTTP Stream/M3U8), i-frame frequency, TS-chunk-size (for M3U8) to name the major points. See [wikipedias explanation on i-frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types).

`MPMoviePlayerController` itself does not impose additional limitations.

To get very exact seeking, use MP4 with a high i-frame frequency. Note, that will dramatically affect the encoded video size.